# Twig to tpl conversion of {{ ' | ' ~ author }}

Tags: opencart

```
{% if theme_option_status[store_id] %}
{% if header_tag[store_id].font_family == header_tag[store_id].font_family %}
{{ a_tag[store_id].color ? 'a { color: #' ~ a_tag[store_id].color ~ '; }' : '' }}
{{ a_tag[store_id].hover_color ? 'a:hover { color: #' ~ a_tag[store_id].hover_color ~ '; }' : '' }}

    {{ total.title ~ " :" }}


    {{ article.date_added_d ~ ' ' ~ article.date_added_m ~ ' ' ~ article.date_added_y }} 
{% if (count % rows == 0) or (count == articles|length ) %}

    {{ (i % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd' }}
{{ " | " ~ article.author }}

    {{ ' | ' ~ author }}
```

This is the twig file code. How can we write this code in tpl file? I am converting OpenCart 3.0.2.0 theme into OpenCart 2.3.0.2. I am facing problem to covert these difficult lines into tpl PHP line. I have done all other code very well, but I couldn't manage to do these lines of code. How can I convert this line in tpl exactly?

Comment: You can convert your Twig code to PHP or TPL here : https://www.easycodetools.com/tool/twig-to-php-converter here, is online twig to PHP converter ( online twig to TPL converter ) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($theme_option_status['store_id']) {
    if ($header_tag['store_id']['font_family'] == $header_tag['store_id']['font_family']){
            echo $a_tag['store_id']['color'] ?  'a { color: #' . $a_tag['store_id']['color'] . '; }' : '';
            echo $a_tag['store_id']['hover_color'] ? 'a:hover { color: #' . $a_tag['store_id']['hover_color'] . '; }' : '';

            echo  $total['title'] . " :" ;

            echo $article['date_added_d'] . ' ' . $article['date_added_m'] . ' ' . $article['date_added_y'];  
            if (($count % $rows == 0) || $count == strlen($articles)) {

            echo ($i % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd' ;
            echo " | " . $article['author'];
            echo ' | ' . $author;
```

Comment: how to convert this value="<?php free_gift_sort_order ? free_gift_sort_order : 0 ?>">   help me @Radhika

Comment: @AskBytes  value="{{ free_gift_sort_order ? free_gift_sort_order : '0' }}"

Comment: my client asking a free gift product to add in cart for customer. among 20 gift products only one product is allowed to add in cart. how to do this. please help me..

Comment: I had done all.. But for that particular gift products customer is allowed to select only one.. how to do this..? please  give me a hints to solve this..